# Multipartform unable to post using OkHttpClient

Tags: java, http, okhttp, http-status-code-503

I am new to using the OkHttpClient and was wondering if anyone could help me.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I am simply trying to enter two teams names into the form on the page http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/head_to_head.sd and then test whether it has successfully loaded or not.

**Issue**

The problem I am having is that it returns this result:

*java.io.IOException: unexpected code: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=503, message=backend read error, url=http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/head_to_head.sd}
    at PredictResult.run(PredictResult.java:28)
    at PredictResult.main(PredictResult.java:39)*

I tried simply using the same format used by the OkHTTP sample code. I'm guessing the issue maybe something to do with that I am not supplying enough data in the HTTP request.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class PredictResult {

private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception{

    RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("team1_name", "Chelsea")
            .addFormDataPart("team2_name", "Manchester")
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.soccerbase.com/teams/head_to_head.sd")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try(Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()){

        if(!response.isSuccessful()) 
            throw new IOException("unexpected code: " + response);

        System.out.println(response.body().string());

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    new PredictResult().run();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

}

}
```

Comment: 503 suggest probably your post url is not correct, are you sure about it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I have decided to use apache commons instead now and that works a lot better.